# Getting error while running spark job from hive. - Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf (state=,code=0)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

Getting error while running spark job from hive CLI

jdbc:hive2://hdpworker.kyvostest.com:10000> select id from sample group by id;
Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf (state=,code=0)

Tried spark job from hive
hive - 1.2
spark - 2.3
hdp 2.6.5

0: jdbc:hive2://hdpworker.kyvostest.com:10000> SET hive.execution.engine=spark;
No rows affected (0.069 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://hdpworker.kyvostest.com:10000> select id from sample group by id;
Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf (state=,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://hdpworker.kyvostest.com:10000>

Job is running fine when run using mr engine.

Comment: it seems like hive is not configured with your spark classpath.